# improve performance - NTFS to ext4

Tags: partitioning, performance, ntfs, ext4

My laptop is 7 year old HP compaq  with ubuntu 12.04. It was dual booting with windows partition. I was not using  windows  for the last 1 year and formatted and the windows drive and removed it.

All the disk partitions are NTFS except the ubuntu partions.

now my laptop is very slow, sometimes it hangs when using firefox, aptana editor etc.

I doubt the slow may be due to fragmented ntfs file sytem. If I convert all drive to ext4 will this improve the performance?

cleaning the laptop fan and dust  make any change in performance ?

Comment: its in ext4 partition

Answer (score 2):

NTFS vs EXT4 will not gain you much if any better performance, it will allow you to use extra chars with files/folders naming and much bigger single file sizes.. read link below.

[EXT4 vs NTFS (A Bit Old But Still Stands)](http://www.overclock.net/a/how-to-change-the-ubuntu-gui)

Overheating on the other hand will effect the computer performance, so a clean heat sink will give you more improvement than a dirty one.

Also note that most of the improvements to be done will depend on your cpu clock/ram amount/hdd write-read speed.

If you have low ram amount the first thing to do is trying a lighter GUI for your ubuntu.

read below

[Changin Ubuntu GUI](http://www.overclock.net/a/how-to-change-the-ubuntu-gui)

Also disabling/Uninstalling services you may not need will improve the performance.

You could always try a fresh/clean install if you do not have a lot to redo on your current computer.

Comment: It was working far better before . this very low performance is about 6 months before. First I thought its due to firefox.

Comment: No. It's really can affect on the system preformance. NTFS daemon is overhead layer that slows all filesystem operations. And migration to Ext4 really can improve the performance in this case.

Comment: Can you please provide CPU + RAM info?
Also can you post the result of "top" Command while running firefox?

Comment: processor : Intel® Pentium(R) Dual CPU T2370 @ 1.73GHz × 2, RAM : 2GB

Comment: Top result http://imgur.com/cgoPzBO

Comment: Everything seems to be fine, no CPU overload nor using swap to cause things going slow, i would say try cleaning the instde of the laptop as a start and check if things work out, also there will be no harm in switching to EXT4 but still may not be much of a help.

Answer (score 0):

> If I convert all drive to ext4 will this improve the performance?

Are the NTFS partitions mounted? But even then I doubt that it'll improve performance.

> cleaning the laptop fan and dust make any change in performance ?

Perhaps if it throttles the CPU due to overheating but most probably: No.

#### Conclusion

Chances are very high that your laptop is very slow because it's 7 years old.

Comment: yes..all the ntfs partitions are mounted and accessing via ubuntu. Laptop is heating up heavily